# Python print each iteration of a while loop

Tags: python

I've created a summation function that takes in a start number and an end number and returns a summed answer between those two points

```
def print_sum_equations(start_number,end_number):
    
    mySum = 0 
    num = start_number

    while num <= end_number:
         mySum += num 
         num += 1  
    print (mySum)
    
print_sum_equations(3,5)
```

It returns 12 which is correct, however, I want my output to look like the following

```py
3 + 4 + 5 = 12
```

rather than just returning the answer. Im still new to python and learning how to iterate while loops so any help is appreciated

Comment: - Your print statement should be inside the while loop (i.e. you have to add indentation to it). - The print statement should come before `num += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def print_sum_equations(start_number,end_number):
    
    vals = [i for i in range(start_number,end_number+1)]

    s = sum(vals)

    for ind,i in enumerate(vals):
        print(f'{i}',end='')
        if ind != end_number-start_number:
            print(' + ',end='')
        else:
            print(f' = {s}')

print_sum_equations(3,5)
```

Comment: Very nice solution, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join` method to get the series from a list of values.

```
val_list = list(range(start_number, end_number+1))
lhs = ' + '.join(val_list)
print ( lhs + ' = ' + str(sum(val_list)) )
```

You could also use a *list comprehension* to get val_list:

```
val_list = [ n for n in range(start_number, end_number+1) ]
```

... but `list(range(...` is more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty new to programming in python, my solution, is pretty simple and easy to read.

```
def print_sum_equations(start_number,end_number):

  mySum = 0 
  num = start_number
  num_list = []
  num_list.append(num)


  while num <= end_number:
     mySum += num 
     num += 1
     num_list.append(num)
  print (mySum)
  num_list.pop()
  print(*num_list, sep="+",end="")
  print("="+str(mySum))

print_sum_equations(2,5)
```